# How to create Illuminate/Support/Facade/App facade for standalone Illuminate IoC Container

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, illuminate-container, laravel-facade

In my standalone (without Laravel) project i want to use Illuminate IoC container. Also i would like to access the app container through `App` facade provided by `illuminate/support` component. I installed both components (v5.0.28). Here is my (simplified) code:

```
function setup_App(){
    $container = new Illuminate\Container\Container();
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::setFacadeApplication($container);
    class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\App', 'App');
}

setup_App();

App::bind('w', 'Widget');
$widget = App::make('w');
```

Unfortunately, trying to bind something results in:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::bind() in ...\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 213
```

Here is the code on that line

```
$instance = static::getFacadeRoot();
...
return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]); // <--- line 213
```

Where `$instance` is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App`, `$method == 'bind'`, `$args[0] == 'w'` and `$args[1] == 'Widget'`.
The problem is that `$instance` is not an instance of `Illuminate\Container\Container` and class `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App` does not have any support for calling arbitrary functions on its static property `$app`.

To make it work i added the following function to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App`:

```
public function __call( $method , array $arguments ) {
    return call_user_func_array(array(static::$app, $method), $arguments);
}
```

But surely editing external component is not the right thing to do!!! Surely someone have encountered this before!

So the question is : What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one key component. The `Application` class needs to be bound to the container. The Facade is looking for a class to be bound to 'app' but nothing is, hence your error. You can fix the problem by binding the `Illuminate\Container\Container` class to 'app':

```
function setup_App(){
    $container = new Illuminate\Container\Container();
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::setFacadeApplication($container);
    $container->singleton('app', 'Illuminate\Container\Container');
    class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\App', 'App');
}

setup_App();

App::bind('w', 'Widget');
```